# Check each response from retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have responses from server if good token as 
`"users":[{"id":"1234","name":"name"}]`

And if bad token as `"users":"logout"`

How I may check response before convert to objects?

I want do this out onResponse method, it is possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the default Retrofit Adapter. When declaring your call in your Retrofit interface use `Call<ResponseBody>` as the response type. When you make the call you'll get a `ResponseBody` object back from which you can access the JSON by calling `body()`. You can then decide how to proceed.